# Ising model simulation offset critical temperature

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I'm writing a simulation of the Ising model in 2D. The model behaves as predicted except for one thing: the critical temperature is roughly 3.5 while it should be near `2/ln(2 + sqrt (2))`.

The project is a C++ program that generates the data, and a shell script that exercises the program. The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/appetrosyan/Ising-Model-simulation.git). Also here's **lattice.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/lattice.h"

using namespace std;

/*
Copy assignment operator, too long to include in the header.
*/
lattice &lattice::operator=(const lattice &other) {
  size_ = other.size_;
  spins_ = other.spins_;
  J_ = other.J_;
  H_ = other.H_;
  delete spins_;
  return *this;
}

void lattice::print() {
  unsigned int area = size_ * size_;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < area; i++) {
    cout << to_symbol(spins_->at(i));
    if (i % size_ == size_ - 1)
      cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

/*
Computes the energy associated with a spin at the given point.

It is explicitly float as that would allow the compiler to make use of multiple
registers instead of keeping track of unneeded precision.  (typically J, H ~ 1).
*/
float lattice::compute_point_energy(int row, int col) {
  int accumulator = get(row + 1, col) + get(row - 1, col) + get(row, col - 1) +
                    get(row, col + 1);
  return -get(row, col) * (accumulator * J_ + H_);
}

/*
Computes total magnetisation in O(n^2). Thread safe
*/
int lattice::total_magnetisation() {
  int sum = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : sum)
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_ * size_; i++) {
    sum += spins_->at(i);
  }
  return sum;
}

int inline to_periodic(int row, int col, int size) {
  if (row < 0 || row >= size)
    row = abs(size - abs(row));
  if (col < 0 || col >= size)
    col = abs(size - abs(col));
  return row * size + col;
}
```

with **lattice.h**

```
#ifndef lattice_h
#define lattice_h

#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

/* Converts spin up/down to easily printable symbols. */
char inline to_symbol(int in) { return in == -1 ? '-' : '+'; }

/* Converts given pair of indices to those with periodic boundary conditions. */
int inline to_periodic(int row, int col, int size) {
  if (row < 0 || row >= size)
    row = abs(size - abs(row));
  if (col < 0 || col >= size)
    col = abs(size - abs(col));
  return row * size + col;
}

class lattice {
private:
  unsigned int size_;
  // vector<bool> would be more space efficient, but it would not allow
  // multithreading
  std::vector<short> *spins_;
  float J_;
  float H_;

public:
  lattice() noexcept : size_(0), spins_(NULL), J_(1.0), H_(0.0) {}
  lattice(int new_size, double new_J, double new_H) noexcept
      : size_(new_size), spins_(new std::vector<short>(size_ * size_, 1)),
        J_(new_J), H_(new_H) {}
  lattice(const lattice &other) noexcept
      : lattice(other.size_, other.J_, other.H_) {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_ * size_; i++)
      spins_->at(i) = other.spins_->at(i);
  }
  lattice &operator=(const lattice &);

  ~lattice() { delete spins_; }
  void print();
  short get(int row, int col) {
    return spins_->at(to_periodic(row, col, size_));
  }
  unsigned int get_size() { return size_; }
  void flip(int row, int col) { spins_->at(to_periodic(row, col, size_)) *= -1; }
  int total_magnetisation();
  float compute_point_energy(int row, int col);
};

#endif
```

and **simulation.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "include/simulation.h"

using namespace std;

/*
Advances the simulation a given number of steps, and updates/prints the statistics
into the given file pointer.

Defaults to stdout.

The number of time_steps is explcitly unsigned, so that linters/IDEs remind
the end user of the file that extra care needs to be taken, as well as to allow
advancing the simulation a larger number of times.
*/
void simulation::advance(unsigned int time_steps, FILE *output) {
  unsigned int area = spin_lattice_.get_size() * spin_lattice_.get_size();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < time_steps; i++) {
    // If we don't update mean_energy_ every time, we might get incorrect
    // thermodynamic behaviour.
    total_energy_ = compute_energy(spin_lattice_);
    double temperature_delta = total_energy_/area - mean_energy_;
    if (abs(temperature_delta) < 1/area){
      cerr<<temperature_delta<<"! Reached equilibrium "<<endl;
    }
    temperature_ += temperature_delta;
    mean_energy_ = total_energy_ / area;
    if (time_ % print_interval_ == 0) {
      total_magnetisation_ = spin_lattice_.total_magnetisation();
      mean_magnetisation_ = total_magnetisation_ / area;
      print_status(output);
    }
    advance();
  }
}

/*
Advances the simulation a single step.

DOES NOT KEEP TRACK OF STATISTICS. Hence private.
*/
void simulation::advance() {
  #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < spin_lattice_.get_size(); row++) {
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < spin_lattice_.get_size(); col++) {
      double dE = compute_dE(row, col);
      double p = r_.random_uniform();
      float rnd = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.);
      if (exp(-dE / temperature_) > rnd) {
        spin_lattice_.flip(row, col);
      }
    }
  }
  time_++;
}

/*
Computes change in energy due to flipping one single spin.

The function returns a single-precision floating-point number, as data cannot under
most circumstances make use of greater precision than that (save J is set to a
non-machine-representable value).

The code modifies the spin lattice, as an alternative (copying the neighborhood
of a given point), would make the code run slower by a factor of 2.25
*/
float simulation::compute_dE(int row, int col) {
  float e_0 =  spin_lattice_.compute_point_energy(row, col);
  return -4*e_0;


}
/*
Computes the total energy associated with spins in the spin_lattice_.

I originally used this function to test the code that tracked energy as the lattice
itself was modified, but that code turned out to be only marginally faster, and
not thread-safe. This is due to a race condition: when one thread uses a neighborhood
of a point, while another thread was computing the energy of one such point in
the neighborhood of (row, col).
*/
double simulation::compute_energy(lattice &other) {
  double energy_sum = 0;
  unsigned int max = other.get_size();
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : energy_sum)
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
      energy_sum += other.compute_point_energy(i, j);
    }
  }
  return energy_sum;
}

void simulation::set_to_chequerboard(int step){
  if (time_ !=0){
    return;
  }else{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i< spin_lattice_.get_size(); ++i){
      for (unsigned int j=0; j<spin_lattice_.get_size(); ++j){
        if ((i/step)%2-(j/step)%2==0){
          spin_lattice_.flip(i, j);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with **simulation.h**

```
#ifndef simulation_h
#define simulation_h

#include "lattice.h"
#include "rng.h"
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

/*
The logic of the entire simulation of the Ising model of magnetism.

This simulation will run and print statistics at a given time interval.
A simulation can be advanced a single time step, or many at a time,
*/
class simulation {
private:
  unsigned int time_ = 0;  // Current time of the simulation.
  rng r_ = rng();
  lattice spin_lattice_;
  double temperature_;
  double mean_magnetisation_ = 1;
  double mean_energy_;
  double total_magnetisation_;
  double total_energy_;
  unsigned int print_interval_ = 1;
  void advance();

public:
  void set_print_interval(unsigned int new_print_interval) { print_interval_ = new_print_interval; }

  simulation(int new_size, double new_temp, double new_J, double new_H)
      : time_(0), spin_lattice_(lattice(new_size, new_J, new_H)), temperature_(new_temp),
        mean_energy_(new_J * (-4)), total_magnetisation_(new_size * new_size),
        total_energy_(compute_energy(spin_lattice_)) {}

  void print_status(FILE *f) {
    f = f==NULL? stdout : f;
    fprintf(f, "%4d\t%e \t%e\t%e\n", time_, mean_magnetisation_,
            mean_energy_, temperature_);
  }
  void advance(unsigned int time_steps, FILE *output);
  double compute_energy(lattice &other);
  float compute_dE(int row, int col);
  void set_to_chequerboard(int step);
  void print_lattice(){
    spin_lattice_.print();
  };
  // void load_custom(const lattice& custom);
};

#endif
```

The output right now looks something like this: [image: Step function near 2.7]
while it should be a step down near 2.26

Comment: You should add the `lattice.h` and `simulation.h` headers to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a few issues in your code:

- The `compute_dE` method returns the wrong energy, as the factor of 2 shouldn't be there. The Hamiltonian of the Ising system is

  [image: energy]

  While you are effectively using

  [image: wrong]
- The `compute_energy` method returns the wrong energy. The method should iterate over each spin pair only once. Something like this should do the trick:

  `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      for (unsigned int j = i + 1; j < max; j++) {
        energy_sum += other.compute_point_energy(i, j);
      }
  }`
- You use a temperature that is updated on the fly instead of using the target temperature. I do not really understand the purpose of that.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. First of all the answer isn't shifted by a factor of 2, if anything it's shifted by less than 50%, (i.e. 1 unit of J). 

Second, when I change either `compute dE` to its half, the system stops converging. It doesn't shift as I wanted, but rather changes behaviour entirely.

Could you please explain more?

Comment: Update: You were right. Not exactly, but you nudged me in the right direction.  `compute_dE`  is off by a factor of 3/2, not 2. There's double the point energy because of flipping the spin, but also sice we're changing the interaction energy for the four surrounding spins, another point energy (not two because of the double counting.)

Comment: Actually, the real issue is that you don't use the input temperature, but, for some reason, you update the temperature throughout the simulation and use that in the acceptance ratio. That's not right. I'll edit the answer accordingly

Comment: I'm not sure about the energy feedback. I'd assumed that the system is being isolated and thus the energy released from aligning the spins heats the system up. If it's not the case, I'd be willing to update the code...

Comment: Well, you are using the acceptance rule that is associated to constant-temperature systems, meaning that you are implicitly coupling the system to a heat bath. I suspect that, if the temperature were to be variable during the course of the simulation, you would have to use a different acceptance rule.